# EXCEL 2010 if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

In Excel 2010 I have a Group of Services called (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6). I'm looking for an `IF` formula that will take my cell (E10) and multiply the number in D10 by the amount in the cell with the rate in cells c5:h5. It should do this based on what service is listed in B10.

Comment: So you have a service that is searching for an if formula in a cell that will do what?  You're question is not very clear.

Comment: please show an example of your sheet and your expected output. You can use [this Text Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) to format your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to Write a Conditional Formula
The basic syntax of the IF formula in Excel is:

=IF(logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false])

logical_test: the condition that you are checking for

[value_if_true]: the result you want if the condition is true

[value_if_false]: the results you want returned if the condition is false

So to check the service in b10 you would do something like ...

```
=IF(B10=C5,E10*C5, IF(B10=D5,E10*D5, IF(B10=E5,E10*E5, IF(B10=F5,E10*F5, IF(B10=G5,E10*G5, IF(B10=H5,E10*H5))))))
```

Comment: Thanks that very helpful. I was trying to make it work by using the content of the cell as the "= to" so Group rather than C5. But using the cell is working as I wanted it to.

Comment: can you please accept answer and vote up.  Also if you pick the cell by clicking you should be able to use fill and have formula work for other rows other than row 10.